# Foundation template on Rails 4

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation

I am working on a project with rails 4.0.0 and foundation-rails 5.0.1 for the last weeks. I found a template on http://www.themplio.com/categories/foundation-free?order%5Bby%5D=purchases&order%5Bdirection%5D=desc that I want to use. But I cant figure out how to separate the files (especially css files) from the template in my rails project files.

Is there a specific way or a tutorial that I can follow to get this working??

Sorry if the answer is too obvious but I am new with rails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how complex of a template you downloaded, it's going to take some work getting the template (which was built for the vanilla foundation) to work with foundation-rails

You should simply be able to add the stylesheets to your assets and let them be included automatically via `<%= stylesheet_link_tag('application') %>` and `*= require_tree .` but if there's more than a few style sheets, and they're in different folders and such you're probably going to be best off taking the HTML and css snippets you like from the template, and then dropping them into your rails app manually to get the best results.

Comment: For now I'm taking the snipptes of my choice but I still got some issues. Because of activeadmin I have already removed the *=require_tree and the vanilla css makes it even harder for me to get them work. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: If you removed `*= require_tree` then you need to just make sure you're loading the css stlye-sheets manually by adding:  `<%= stylesheet_link_tag('custom_sheet') %>` to your layout

Comment: This is a helpful tip. It didn't even cross my mind that this is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

In the folder that you download the two important folders are `javascripts` & `stylesheets`. You can  manually add these files to you rails app at `app/assets/javascripts` & `app/assets/stylesheets`. Files in these folders will be automatically included.

You can then use the html body content in `index.html` file in the downloaded folder in your rails `html.erb` views - that will get you started.

Comment: Looks like he's already using foundation-rails, hence the frustration

Comment: I've removed that line. Cheers.